# Download East African NDVI data for 5*5km grids

Tags: data-request

I would like to download NDVI data

http://www.mathworks.com/examples/mapping/529-exporting-images-and-raster-grids-to-geotiff

Answer (score 1):

Searching for 'NDVI' led me to [a page from the NASA Earth Observatory](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/MeasuringVegetation/measuring_vegetation_2.php) website.  So I then searched data.nasa.gov, and got back a few links ... I have no idea which one is what you want, though:

https://data.nasa.gov/data?search=NDVI&category=